# Testing drug benefit on a group of ten people

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

**Problem:**  (from page 33 of *Practical Nonparametric Statistics*, by W. J. Conover).

> Assume that every patient with a particular type of disease has the probability 0.1 of being cured within a week, if the patient is given no treatment for the disease. Ten patients with that type of disease are given a new type of drug. After one week 9 out of 10 patients are cured.
>
> (a) What is the probability that at least 9 patients are cured if the drug is assumed to have no curative effects?
> (b) In your opinion, would you consider this drug beneficial?
> (c) What sample space did you use in this analysis?
> (d) What probability function did you define on the sample space?
> (e) What is the name of the probability distribution of your random variable?

**My question:** What is the complement of the event "being cured within a week without treatment"?

I've been stuck on this problem for a week.

Comment: page 33 of *which* text? Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2):

a) Let $X$ be our binomial random variable.  Assuming all trials are independent:
$$P(X\geq9)=
\left( {\begin{array}{*{10}c} 
9 \\ 
10 \\ 
\end{array}} \right)(0.1)^9(0.9)^1  +
\left( {\begin{array}{*{10}c} 
10 \\ 
10 \\ 
\end{array}} \right)(0.1)^{10}(0.9)^0 = 0.000 000 009 1
$$

b) Though I am not fond of the phrasing of the question, the answer is almost certainly "Yes".  There is a very low probability that 9 people or more would have been cured by random chance alone, so it would appear that the drug is having a positive effect.  Of course, "very low probability" is a relative term, and the answer to this question really rests in the degree of confidence you are seeking.  "Beneficial" is also a very subjective term.  If your idea of "beneficial" is the ability to draw direct causality from the use of the drug, then that's a different question with many more considerations.

c) The set of all $ 2^{10} $ possible outcomes.

d) Let $ X $ be our binomial random variable.

$$ P(X \geq k) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=k}^{n}\left( {\begin{array}{*{10}c} 
i \\ 
n \\ 
\end{array}} \right)(0.1)^i(0.9)^{n-i} $$

e) Binomial random variable.

**Edit:** To answer your other question about the complement of the event "being cured within a week without treatment", the population in question is all patients with the disease who do not receive treatment.  If your event contains all of these patients who are cured within a week, then the complement of that is simply those patients in that population who are *not* cured within a week.  Thanks to @whuber for this catch (despite the fact that it rendered my fun pictogram moot!).

Comment: Because your analysis focuses solely on information about *untreated* patients (regardless of whether the patients were actually treated), the lack of treatment should not be part of the definition of the event "being cured within a week without treatment." Thus the complement consists of people who are cured in a week without treatment.  BTW, "$\gt$" means *strictly* greater than. Wherever this symbol appears in your post it must be replaced by "$\ge$" (greater than or equal) in order for the statements to be correct.

Comment: Agreed!  Thanks very much for the catch (and for pointing out the >, ≥ error).

Answer (score 0):

> what is the complement of the event "being cured within a week w/o treatment"?

The complement to an event is anything else in the universe of events other than the event itself.  I the case of what you're asking, the complement of the event, $A$, "event that being cured within a week w/o treatment" is all events except for a patient being cured within a week  In this instance let us assume there are five possible other possible disjoint sets (though there could be other ways of breaking these down):

not being cured <= 1 week w/o treatment ($B$), not being cured > 1 week w/o treatment ($C$), not being cured > 1 week w/ treatment ($D$), being cured > 1 week w/ treatment ($E$), being cured <= 1 week w/ treatment ($F$)

So if we take $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$ to be all possible events in the universe (U) then

$A \cup B \cup C \cup D \cup E \cup F = U$

Thus the complement to event, $A$, is all other events within the universe not contained in A, which in this case is:

$A^{C} = B  \cup C \cup D \cup E \cup F$

(Thanks to @whuber for clarification suggestions)

Comment: You appear to skip over something that may be important to the OP: the complement of an event (which is a set of outcomes) is a *set*, not a probability.  This answer only gives the *probability* of the complement without defining the complement or characterizing it in this situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the improvements. I am concerned about one possible confusion, though: you seem to equate "event" with "outcome." Because the distinction is fundamental it would seem important to be clear about it. The complement of "being cured [within] a week" is described as *not* being cured within a week. It's as simple as that. In terms of populations, the relevant one is "patients with the disease who go without treatment." The event consists of all such patients who are cured within a week; its complement consists of everyone else in that population.